# Change mimosa web package build directory

Tags: node.js, mimosa

I am trying to change the directory of Mimosa's "dist" folder. It is currently set via the node package "mimosa-web-package", and there is a config file in there. However, I do not want this config to be overridden if I update my node modules.

I have looked on Mimosa's page to see if there is an option to change, however I cannot work out how they are linked.

Anybody encountered this issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set this to whatever you want in your mimosa.config file:

```
webPackage.outPath: __dirname + "/nameOfBuildDir"
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you found the answer, but hopefully this helps...

[mimosa-web-package](https://github.com/dbashford/mimosa-web-package) has its documentation on its GitHub page instead of the website because it isn't a "default" module that comes packaged with Mimosa.  The [config](https://github.com/dbashford/mimosa-web-package#default-config) for mimosa-web-package is what controls that particular setting, and yep, its `outPath` that you want to change. It is set to `dist` by default.

`webPackage.outPath: "nameOfBuildDir"` should also work in the case you mention above.